# How to easily invoke Simple REST Service trigerred using Arduino UNO + ESP8266 WIFI Shield programmed with AT command?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

My Question is How to easily invoke Simple REST Service trigerred using **Arduino UNO + ESP8266 WIFI Shield** programmed with AT command? I am new to this Subject and gone through many tutorial over internet but so far I could not making this working as per my requirement

**My Requirement:** Invoke a simple Get request originated from Arduino Uno and via ESP8266 WIFI Shield to submit to server and process the response.

**What all I have done so far:**

1. Used below Blynk example to Submit Up time to the Server and View in Mobile**This is Working which means hardware setup at my side should be ok**, but I dont want to Submit request to Blynk Server and I want to Submit request to my REST server and first of all I want to do a simple GET request may be to any already working API for ex: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1

   ```
   #define BLYNK_PRINT Serial
    #include <ESP8266_Lib.h>
    #include <BlynkSimpleShieldEsp8266.h>

    // You should get Auth Token in the Blynk App.
    // Go to the Project Settings (nut icon).
    char auth[] = "xyz";

    // Your WiFi credentials.
    // Set password to "" for open networks.
    char ssid[] = "xyz";
    char pass[] = "xyz";

    // Hardware Serial on Mega, Leonardo, Micro...
    //#define EspSerial Serial1

    // or Software Serial on Uno, Nano...
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
    SoftwareSerial EspSerial(2, 3); // RX, TX

    // Your ESP8266 baud rate:
    #define ESP8266_BAUD 115200

    ESP8266 wifi(&EspSerial);

    BlynkTimer timer;

    void myTimerEvent()
    {
      // You can send any value at any time.
      // Please don't send more that 10 values per second.
      Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, millis() / 1000);
    }

    void setup()
    {
      // Debug console
      Serial.begin(115200);

      // Set ESP8266 baud rate
      EspSerial.begin(ESP8266_BAUD);
      delay(10);

      Blynk.begin(auth, wifi, ssid, pass);
      // You can also specify server:
      //Blynk.begin(auth, wifi, ssid, pass, "blynk-cloud.com", 80);
      //Blynk.begin(auth, wifi, ssid, pass, IPAddress(192,168,1,100), 8080);

      // Setup a function to be called every second
      timer.setInterval(1000L, myTimerEvent);
    }

    void loop()
    {
      Blynk.run();
      timer.run(); // Initiates BlynkTimer
    }
   ```

Output :

```
  ___  __          __
   / _ )/ /_ _____  / /__
  / _  / / // / _ \/  '_/
 /____/_/\_, /_//_/_/\_\
        /___/ v0.6.1 on Arduino Uno

[517] Connecting to xyz
[13550] AT version:1.1.0.0(May 11 2016 18:09:56)
SDK version:1.5.4(baaea 1
[23591] Failed to connect WiFi
[31752] Ready (ping: 11ms).
[70474] Ready (ping: 12ms).
[86528] Ready (ping: 13ms).
```

Though I get Failed to connect to wifi but probably it retries and works there after as I can see timer in Mobile APP which is progressing.

2. Invoke HTTP request using AT Command, but I am getting output as ">" which I am not able to get as why the output is like this:

   `````
   #include <SoftwareSerial.h>

   SoftwareSerial ESP8266(2, 3);

   String Network = "xyz";
   String Password = "xyz";


   void setup()
   {

     Serial.begin(9600);

     ESP8266.begin(115200);
     ESP8266.println("AT+CIOBAUD=9600");
     readESP8266(4000);

     ESP8266.begin(9600); 
     InitESP8266();
     ConnectToWebsite();
   }

   void loop()
   {
      while(ESP8266.available())
      {   
        Serial.println(ESP8266.readString());
      } 

   }

   /* Function to initialise ESP8266 */
   void InitESP8266()
   { 

     ESP8266.println("AT");
     readESP8266(2000);

     ESP8266.println("AT+CWMODE=3"); //Wifi mode
     readESP8266(5000);

     ESP8266.println("AT+CWJAP=\""+ Network + "\",\"" + Password +"\""); //connect wifi
     readESP8266(10000);

     ESP8266.println("AT+CIFSR"); // IP adress
     readESP8266(1000);

     ESP8266.println("AT+CIPMUX=1");  // multiple connections
     readESP8266(1000);

   }

   /* Function to connect to the server */
   void ConnectToWebsite()
   {

     ESP8266.println("AT+CIPSTART=1,\"TCP\",\"jsonplaceholder.typicode.com\",80"); //connect to website
     readESP8266(10000);

     ESP8266.println("AT+CIPSEND=1,114");
     readESP8266(2000);

     String httpreq = "GET /posts/1 HTTP/1.1";
     // Make a HTTP request:
     ESP8266.println(httpreq);
     readESP8266(10000);

     readESP8266(5000);

     //Serial.println("\r\n");
   }


   //read and display message
   void readESP8266(const int timeout)
   {
     String reponse = "";
     long int time = millis();
     while( (time+timeout) > millis())
     {
       while(ESP8266.available())
       {
         char c = ESP8266.read();
         reponse+=c;
       }
     }
     Serial.print(reponse);   
   }````
   `````

Output:

```
OK

OK
WIFI DISCONNECT
WIFI CONNECTED
WIFI GOT IP

OK
+CIFSR:APIP,"192.168.4.1"
+CIFSR:APMAC,"abcd"
+CIFSR:STAIP,"192.168.0.169"
+CIFSR:STAMAC,"abcd"

OK

OK
1,CONNECT

OK

OK
> 1,CLOSED
```

3. If I use WIFI ESP then I am getting following error

   `````
   // Emulate Serial1 on pins 6/7 if not present
   #ifndef HAVE_HWSERIAL1
   #include "SoftwareSerial.h"
   SoftwareSerial Serial1(2, 3); // RX, TX
   #endif

   char ssid[] = "xyz";            // your network SSID (name)
   char pass[] = "xyz";        // your network password
   int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;     // the Wifi radio's status

   char server[] = "arduino.cc";

   // Initialize the Ethernet client object
   WiFiEspClient client;

   void setup()
   {
     // initialize serial for debugging
     Serial.begin(115200);
     // initialize serial for ESP module
     Serial1.begin(9600);
     // initialize ESP module
     WiFi.init(&Serial1);

     // check for the presence of the shield
     if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
       Serial.println("WiFi shield not present");
       // don't continue
       //while (true);
     }

     // attempt to connect to WiFi network
     while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) {
       Serial.print("Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: ");
       Serial.println(ssid);
       // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network
       status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
     }

     // you're connected now, so print out the data
     Serial.println("You're connected to the network");

     printWifiStatus();

     Serial.println();
     Serial.println("Starting connection to server...");
     // if you get a connection, report back via serial
     if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
       Serial.println("Connected to server");
       // Make a HTTP request
       client.println("GET /asciilogo.txt HTTP/1.1");
       client.println("Host: arduino.cc");
       client.println("Connection: close");
       client.println();
     }
   }

   void loop()
   {
     // if there are incoming bytes available
     // from the server, read them and print them
     while (client.available()) {
       char c = client.read();
       Serial.write(c);
     }

     // if the server's disconnected, stop the client
     if (!client.connected()) {
       Serial.println();
       Serial.println("Disconnecting from server...");
       client.stop();

       // do nothing forevermore
       while (true);
     }
   }


   void printWifiStatus()
   {
     // print the SSID of the network you're attached to
     Serial.print("SSID: ");
     Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

     // print your WiFi shield's IP address
     IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
     Serial.print("IP Address: ");
     Serial.println(ip);

     // print the received signal strength
     long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
     Serial.print("Signal strength (RSSI):");
     Serial.print(rssi);
     Serial.println(" dBm");
   }````
   `````

Output:

`````
````[WiFiEsp] I >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] Initializing ESP module
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>> 
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] Cannot initialize ESP module
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] No tag found
WiFi shield not present
Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: xyz
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
`````

```
Please let me know in case you figure out the issue.
```

Comment: you don't set the AT baud rate in the WiFiEsp sketch. use `AT+UART=9600,8,1,0,0` to set 9600 baud as default

Comment: @jsotola tried formatting with ctrl+k but it's not taking effect, looks like a bug in stack overflow :D

Comment: @Juraj meaning set these in WiFi esp sketch code??

Comment: It’s not a bug in Stack Overflow.

Comment: doesn't matter how you execute it. it will be remembered as default

Comment: @Rajesh To make a code block inside of an enumeration, you need to add another 4 spaces at the beginning of each line, so 4 spaces for the enumeration item and another 4 for the code block. That is not a bug, but just the way, that such markdown languages work, that SE uses. It is easier to copy the text into a decent text editor, command it to indent the corresponding lines by 4 spaces and then copy it back to the question editor. The toolbar of the editor is only meant for easier formatting

Comment: Done formatting as requested

Comment: Judge from the sketches you've tried, you are jumping from one example code to another example code without understanding how actually the code works. On your sketch 2, if a request-URI is not a full URL, you need to send extra http header "Host: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com" to indicate which server you want to get data from, and you also need to send an extra CR-LF (as in your sketch 3 and see [HTTP/1.1 Request](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html)). On sketch 3, as mentioned by @Juraj, you need to setup the baud rate with AT command.

Comment: Thanks @hcheung, I am able to send request after formatting as suggested but unable to read response. Any idea what could be the issue now: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/77341/unable-to-read-arduinoesp8266-full-get-response